# Pytest: How to set default import-mode to importlib?

Tags: pytest

pytest-6.0 introduced [a new 'import-mode' option dubbed 'importlib'](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html) along with the declaration:

> "We intend to make importlib the default in future releases."

If I adopt it in advance, I'm not sure how I will go remembering to always specify `--import-mode=importlib` on the command line.  I tried adding a few variations to the `[tool.pytest.ini_options]` tag in `pyproject.toml` without success.

Is there some way I can specify it in a config file?

Comment: Have you tried `addopts` in `pytest.ini`?

Comment: Or in `pyproject.toml` for that matter, would also work.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `pyproject.toml` this seems to work...

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--import-mode=importlib"
```